# How can I use PySys to test an Apama correlator

Tags: apama, pysys

I know that I can use PySys to test my application, I've written a run.py file with my execute and verify but when I run it nothing seems to happen. I tried adding an init function and printing from there just to see if my test class was being instantiated but I got no output. Am I missing something?

I use pyhton run.py to execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're trying to run the test.  The `run.py` file just defines the execute and verify actions; it never calls them.  What you need to do is:

1. Navigate to your test directory in an Apama command prompt
2. Execute `pysys run`

You can also execute this from a higher directory, and it will execute all tests in that tree (it's recursive by default).  Use `pysys -h` for help.

Comment: Kudos to Madhur for improving the formatting in my answer: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also find examples of pysys tests in the Apama\samples folder. The readme file in the folder gives more details on how to run pysys tests.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.)